# Most efficient way of checking the max level?

Tags: php

So I didn't know what I should have named the title, sorry about that.

Anyways, I am creating something like.. you got resources which you can upgrade buildings with. I want different buildings to have different max levels. So what would be the best way to do this? (the checking if building is max leveled)

Let's say I have a page where you can see all your buildings, levels of the buildings and "Upgrade" or something like that.

```
**Upgrade page.**
House (level 4) UpgradeButton
Big House (level 5) NoUpgradeButton
Apartment (level 2) UpgradeButton
```

Let's say level 5 is max level for "Big House".
Would it be good to have like a file named building_levels.php, then do a variable for each max level? Like:

```
$house_maxlvl = 5;
$bighouse_maxlvl = 5;
```

etc?

I saw something else using something like..:

```
$cl_builds->add_build("House", "house");
$cl_builds->set_woodprice("90", "1.26");

$cl_builds->add_build("Big House", "bighouse");
$cl_builds->set_woodprice("120", "1.26");
```

How would I do something like that? PDO? And how does it know which building to add the woodprice to?

Comment: I would rather use Constances instead of Variables, sine the values isn't going to change

Comment: @j_s_stack Alright, thanks for your answer. Do you know about my second "question"? (the PDO one at the bottom)

Comment: I don't know about PDO, and I don't know how much you know about PHP OOP (object-oriented programming) Therefore its hard to say. The Code Example you included doesn't look right (but i don't know the code behind it). The better way would be to create an object for every house

Comment: @j_s_stack Now that you mention objects, I think that's what they used. How does it know which building to add the info to tho? (the wood price for example) Sorry if I'm confusing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)  I would rather use Constances instead of Variables, sine the values isn't going to Change.
You kann declare Consts in PHP with the definde Function:

```
define('NAME'.'value');
```

2) OOP - object-oriented programming would be one possible solution here.

You need to create a Class: (You can add variables and functions)

```
class=  building{
  var name = "";
  var price = "";

  function setData($Name,$woodprice){
     $this->Name = $Name;
     $this->Price = $woodprice;
  }
}
```

Then you can create Instantces of your Class:

```
$house = new building;
$house->setData('House','1.20');

$bighouse = new building;
$bighouse->setData('Big House','1.20');
```

You can also directly Access (Get & Set) Variables in the clas

```
echo $house->Name;
```

Also you can add a Database query to the addData function to get the data from a Database.
Hope that helped a bit.